# How to display same format repeater for each row that has the same cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 50 different format repeaters. Each has to be bind according to the state.

I created a gridview with checkboxes. Whichever rows are checked to display those rows data in the corresponding repeater.

I am sending to the stored procedure multiple parameter and return a datatable. I loop through the datatable and on button click I get all repeaters except when the state is the same - it returns only the last one. I debug and the code runs through it but overwrites the previous row that had that state. How can I display all repeaters for the same state?

```
protected void GetVinData()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"]);
    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmmd.CommandText = c
    cmmd.Connection = cn;
    cn.Open();

    try
    {
        cmmd.Parameters.Add("@POLICY", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmmd.Parameters["@POLICY"].Value = ddlPolicy.SelectedValue;
        cmmd.Parameters.Add("@VIN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmmd.Parameters["@VIN"].Value = txtMsg.Value;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"]);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "GetAllVinNumbers";
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@POLICY", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@POLICY"].Value = ddlPolicy.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VIN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@VIN"].Value = dr["VIN"].ToString();

                if (dr["STATE"].ToString() == "AL")
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                        }
                        Repeater_AL.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Repeater_AL.DataBind();
                        Repeater_AL.Visible = true;
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                        lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else if (dr["STATE"].ToString() == "AK")
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            conn.Open();
                        Repeater_AK.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Repeater_AK.DataBind();
                        Repeater_AK.Visible = true;
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose(); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                        lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }

                }
                else if (dr["STATE"].ToString() == "AZ")
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            conn.Open();
                        Repeater_AZ.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Repeater_AZ.DataBind();
                        Repeater_AZ.Visible = true;
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                        lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                        if (Repeater_AZ.Visible == true)
                        {
                            Repeater_AZ.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }


                } ... and so on for 50 states
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slight refactoring may help:

```
protected void BindVin(string state)
{
    Repeater rpt = null;
    Control ctl = null;
    string name = string.Empty;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    name = "Repeater_" + state;
    ctl = Page.FindControl(name);
    rpt = ctl as Repeater;
    if (rpt != null) {
        try {
            conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DBConnection"));
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "GetAllVinNumbers"; // should this have the state to get VINs for?
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@POLICY", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters("@POLICY").Value = ddlPolicy.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@VIN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters("@VIN").Value = dr("VIN").ToString();

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
                conn.Open();
            }

            rpt.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rpt.DataBind();
            rpt.Visible = true;

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
        } finally {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

protected void GetVinData()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"]);
    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmmd.CommandText = c
    cmmd.Connection = cn;
    cn.Open();

    try
    {
        cmmd.Parameters.Add("@POLICY", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmmd.Parameters["@POLICY"].Value = ddlPolicy.SelectedValue;
        cmmd.Parameters.Add("@VIN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmmd.Parameters["@VIN"].Value = txtMsg.Value;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            BindVin(dr["STATE"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: // should this have the state to get VINs for? The stored procedures returns a table with all the selected VIN numbers. The table includes all the info about that vin. The two methods you send me are perfect because I get to see the approach. Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: Here is an addition to the code for those you have the name ct100$MainContent$Repeater_AZ                                MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;
        ContentPlaceHolder                                 MainContent = ctl00.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;

Comment: @Lily: Your proposed edits don't do anything as you don't reference the variable `MainContent` after you've set the value. Also `ct100$MainContent$Repeater_AZ MasterPage` is the "as-rendered-to-the-client" `name` attribute. It is not what you would call it in your server-side code. Set a breakpoint after those variables are set in the `BindVin` method. They are very likely to be `null`.

Comment: I wrote after ctl = MainContent.FindControl(name) and it found it. Before it was getting to if(rpt!=null) and jumping to catch saying Object not set to a reference. I ran a method to find all the id's and  names and then I saw that I need the MainContent. Aside from this I really like how you code do you have a website where  you post code? Thank you.

Comment: Okay, glad it's working. To answer your last question: "No. I do not have a website where I post code (well, other than my answers here)."

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to email me all different type of code. Mostly I am trying to understand on row databound and on row created. lily.gazal@yahoo.com Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like an excellent idea for a question to post here on SO. You should phrase that in the form of a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067883/how-does-onrowdatabound-and-onrowcreated-work here is the link to the question. I cannot find words for helping with understanding these two events.